# Получить список слов в тексте и частоту их повторения, и занести результат в DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp

Есть текстовый файл со следующим текстом: "Пример пример для питона для теста". Не учитывать регистр, т.е. `Пример = пример`
Нужно получить список (слово, частота) типа:

`пример 2
для 2
питона 1
теста 1`

И все это занести в DF, 1 столбец : "слово"  , 2 столбец : "частота"

Comment: Не видно вашего кода в вопросе. Что конкретно не получается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
def data_freq(string: str):
    data_frame_dict = {
        'word': [],
        'frequency': []
    }
    for k, v in Counter(string.lower().split()).items():
        data_frame_dict['word'].append(k)
        data_frame_dict['frequency'].append(v)

    return pd.DataFrame(data_frame_dict)
```

Answer (score 3):

Пример:

```
from nltk import word_tokenize, FreqDist
import pandas as pd

text = "Пример, пример - для питона для теста!"
fdist = FreqDist(word.lower() for word in word_tokenize(text) if word.isalpha())
df = pd.Series(fdist).reset_index(name="freq").rename(columns={"index":"word"})
```

результат:

```
In [21]: df
Out[21]:
     word  freq
0  пример     2
1     для     2
2  питона     1
3   теста     1
```

Answer (score -1):

Держи, можешь доработать, так как я не очень шарю в pandas таблица выводиться не совсем так как хотелось бы, но похожие слова считает правильно

```
import re
import pandas as pd

frequency = {}
document_text = open(text.txt 'r')
text_string = document_text.read().lower()
text_string = document_text.lower()
match_pattern = re.findall(r'\b[а-я]{1,15}\b', text_string)

for word in match_pattern:
    count = frequency.get(word, 0)
    frequency[word] = count + 1

frequency_list = frequency.keys()

for words in frequency_list:
    d = {'слово': [words], 'частота': [frequency[words]]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
    print('-'*100)
    print(df)
```

Comment: Вот зачем такое постить?

Comment: Я что то не понял в вопросе или что то не так сделал?

Comment: И то и другое сразу. Если вы не уверены в ответе или заранее знаете, что ваш ответ не отвечает на вопрос, то просто писать что-то не имеет смысла. Это не корректно по отношению к автору вопроса. тем более в формулировке "я сам не понимаю, но ты можешь доработать".